# Add combo box in OfficeJS Excel

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx, excel-web-addins

I am developing an add-in with Office JS, In need add combobox when click in a bottom but I dont see this options it is possible

add combobox with OfficeJS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combo boxes are not supported in OfficeJS for ribbon customizations. Supported control types are:

- Simple buttons - trigger specific actions.
- Menus - simple menu dropdown with buttons that trigger actions.

Read more about ribbon customizations in the [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) article.

But you may consider creating a task pane with any controls. There are not limitations on the controls used for task panes (unlike ribbon).

Remember that you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.